# Using API of a website on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create an wp7 application that converts the URL to PDF document. I want to use the joliprint.com service for my app. I created a textbox(**named as textBox1**)for URL's and button(**named as button1**)for submitting the URL's. Can anybody help me with this or can anybody provide me some samples or examples for this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You could see for iTextSharp to do the trick but I'm not sure if will run on WP7

Comment: I am new to these API things, so i dont know how to start. Do you have any samples?

Answer (score 0):

Run Fiddler and manually make a request using your browser. From the information that Fiddler gathers, you should be able to identify the query format. You are looking for the HTTP verb (GET, etc.) and the URL format (http://website.com/process.aspx?url=URLSUBMITTED). Once you have this, you can make an HTTPWebRequest from your app.

You should probably make sure that what you are doing isn't against the terms of use of the website. There may be a reason they don't have a published API... Asking permission is best, especially if the you expect to be making lots of calls to this site.